# How to prevent npm from installing different versions of the same package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

For example, given two node modules, `a` and `b`.

**a/package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "fastify": "3.24.0"
  }
}
```

**b/package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "a": "*",
    "fastify": "^3.24.0"
  }
}
```

After running `npm install` in `b`, there are two versions of `fastify` in `b`'s `node_modules`. One is `node_modules/fastify` (3.25.0), the other is `node_modules/a/node_modules/fastify` (3.24.0), which makes the instances created by `fastify` in the two modules (`a` and `b`) respectively belong to different classes and causes problems.

It's weird that npm doesn't just choose to use one version (such as 3.24.0) of the same package that fits all semver conditions.

Comment: Can you remove the carrot sign ^ from fastify package in b/package.json? That way you will get one fastiy version.

Comment: @LazarNikolic However, once the `a` module updates and upgrades its `fastify` dependency, there are two different versions again.

Comment: Found a reluctantly acceptable solution: use pnpm which can set resolutions in package.json. I set `"resolutions": { "fastify": "3" }`, and pnpm installed just one fastify ^3.